# MVC3. Ajax Confirmation comes twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a list of Products. Each line has 'Delete' action. When I try to delete any row everything is true, but after second deleting ajax confirmation comes twice. Please help.

There are product list view.

```
@model IEnumerable<Domain.Entities.Product>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Products";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
<h1>Products</h1>
<table class="Grid">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@item.Name</td>
        <td>@item.Description</td>
        <td>@item.Price</td>
        <td>
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("DeleteProduct", "Admin", 
                    new AjaxOptions { 
                                      Confirm="Product was deleted!", 
                                      UpdateTargetId="DeleteProduct"
                                    }))
            {
                @Html.Hidden("Id", item.Id)
                <input type="image" src="../Images/Icons/DeleteIcon.jpg" />
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

There are AdminController

```
[Authorize]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository productRepository;

    public AdminController(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        this.productRepository= productRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult Products()
    {
        return View(productRepository.Products);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteProduct(int id)
    {
        Product prod = productRepository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
        if (prod != null)
        {
            productRepository.DeleteProduct(prod);
            TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} was deleted", prod.Name);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Products");
    }
}
```

And finally _AdminLayout.cshtml

```
<html>
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Admin.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="DeleteProduct">
    @if (TempData["message"] != null) {
        <div class="Message">@TempData["message"]</div>
    }
    @RenderBody()
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you are calling the `DeleteProduct` action with AJAX and this action is performing a Redirect to the Products action. Except that the Products action is returning a full HTML instead of a partial. So you get the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` injected twice into your DOM. So you get 2 confirmations on the second delete, 3 on the third and so on.

So start by defining a partial containing the table records (`~/Views/Admin/_Products.cshtml`):

```
@model IEnumerable<Domain.Entities.Product>

<div>@ViewData["message"]</div>

<table class="Grid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model) 
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@item.Description</td>
                <td>@item.Price</td>
                <td>
                    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("DeleteProduct", "Admin", 
                            new AjaxOptions { 
                                Confirm = "Are you sure you wanna delete this product?", 
                                UpdateTargetId = "products"
                            })
                    )
                    {
                        @Html.Hidden("Id", item.Id)
                        <input type="image" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Icons/DeleteIcon.jpg")" alt="Delete" />
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and then modify your main view so that it uses this partial:

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Products</h1>
<div id="products">
    @Html.Partial("_Products")
</div>
```

and finally modify your `DeleteProduct` controller action so that it no longer does any redirects but returns the partial instead after deleting the record:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteProduct(int id)
{
    Product prod = productRepository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
    if (prod != null)
    {
        productRepository.DeleteProduct(prod);
        ViewData["message"] = string.Format("{0} was deleted", prod.Name);
    }

    return PartialView("_Products", productRepository.Products);
}
```

Comment: Thank u for the answer, I just figure this at the same time as I was viewing you answer.

Comment: Great, so we are on the same wave. Hopefully my answer answer will provide you with a working example that you could extend and adapt to your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You have everything funneled through a single AJAX operation, so the click of delete is finding two items to delete on the second click. The way to handle this is work some magic on resetting the bound items so either a) the deleted item is set up to show it is already deleted once confirmed or b) rebinding the entire set of items after a delete to get rid of the item that has been deleted.

As long as you continue to have an item that the client believes has not been deleted, you will continue to "delete both" each time you click.

Comment: Thanks for answer. As I understood third time should be three confirmation, yes? But third delete has four confirmation and fourth delete is 8 confirmation.

Comment: Not sure how that is happening, but you are ending up with a binary progression. First click == 1. Second ==2. Third == 4. Fourth == 8. Fifth should equal 16, and so on. I would still look at rebinding the list after a delete in some JavaScript code so you have a logical reset.

Comment: I read some sections about my problem and found that jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js file is duplicated. What do you think about this?

Comment: That could explain a binary rather than a linear progression if both methods are being fired. I would imagine you would be able to examine this in debug.

Comment: I attach jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js file twice in _AdminLayout.cshtml and got two confirmation for first delete.