# ajax.actionlink confirmation popup shows twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an [Ajax.Actionlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) for delete with confirm message, but the confirm message will show up twice after the first deletion when clicked "OK".

Basically, when I delete the first record, the confirm message show. I click on ok, the delete happens and the partial view list rerender. I click on another record for delete, the confirm message show. I click on "OK", weird thing happen - the record is deleted, but the confirm message popup again.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", 
                 "Delete", 
                 new { id = item.AnnouncementSID }, 
                 new AjaxOptions
                {
                  Confirm = "Are you sure you want to delete this announcement?",
                  HttpMethod = "POST",
                  UpdateTargetId = "divAnnounceList"
                }, new { @class = "actionLink" })

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC3. Ajax Confirmation comes twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778693/mvc3-ajax-confirmation-comes-twice). And your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14148376/29407

Comment: I found the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778693/mvc3-ajax-confirmation-comes-twice

Comment: Shot for `Confirm` option in the `AjaxOptions`. I never knew it existed. How convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For clarification to future searchers.:

The problem here is that you are calling the Delete action with AJAX and this action is performing a Redirect to the Announcements action. Except that the Announcement action is returning a full HTML instead of a partial. So you get the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js injected twice into your DOM. So you get 2 confirmations on the second delete, 3 on the third and so on.

Think this is what is happening